# Change folder sorting in wysiwyg Magento 2

Tags: php, sorting, magento, magento2

Coding to create a store with Magento I found a 'problem' I would like to solve.

Whenever I open the file system in Magento using Wysiwyg, the folders are not sorted at all.

Find here an example  [image]

I would like to have the folders sorted by name ASC.  I tried modiying the Storage class by creating a preference of `vendor\magento\module-cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage.php`

and it actually works for images inside but not for folders!

[image: As you can see images are sorted but folders]

My big question is, how can I sort this folder collection by name? Where can I find the files for this changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage` class has method `getDirsCollection`

Extend it by calling `setOrder` setter

```
$collection = $this->getCollection($path)
    ->setCollectDirs(true)
    ->setCollectFiles(false)
    ->setCollectRecursively(false)
    // ===> setter <===
    ->setOrder(
        'name',
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC
    )
;
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much!